# Hex String Detected as Base64

Tags: ios, hex, base64, nsdata

I'm passing Hex string to this method but it still detects the string as base64.
My string is: 546869732069732073696d706c6520737472696e672e

```
+(BOOL)isBase64Data:(NSString *)input
    {
        input=[[input componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
     if ([input length] % 4 == 0) {
        static NSCharacterSet *invertedBase64CharacterSet = nil;
        if (invertedBase64CharacterSet == nil) {
            invertedBase64CharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet
                                            characterSetWithCharactersInString:
                                                @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="]
                                           invertedSet];
        }
        BOOL isbase64 = [input rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invertedBase64CharacterSet
                                               options:NSLiteralSearch].location   == NSNotFound;

    return isbase64;
}
return NO;
}
```

Have followed several links on net with above code marked true. But somehow it's not working with the string I provided.